# Strikeout an entire table row

Tags: html, css

Is there a way to strike out an entire table row (line-throuth the whole cell, not just the text)?

I have tried applying

```
text-decoration:line-through;
```

at both the column & row level, but this only strikes out the text, not the entire cell.

Is there a way to strike the entire row?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Linethrough/strikethrough a whole HTML table row](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4619542/linethrough-strikethrough-a-whole-html-table-row) (I know this is an older question, but that one has a better answer)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably the easiest way to do this, if all the rows are the same height, is to apply a background image to it that just has a big line through the center, the same color as the test.

Comment: thanks chacha.. it worked fine.. i just added transparent gif extra.. :)