# Linethrough/strikethrough a whole HTML table row

Tags: html, css, html-table, row, strikethrough

After some research, I couldn't find an answer to this question. There was [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1758584/css-line-through-not-being-removed) but it didn't really answer my question. I would like to "strikethrough" a complete HTML table row in CSS, not just the text in it. Is it at all possible? From the example that I linked, it seems tr styling doesn't even work in Firefox. (And anyway, text-decoration only applies on text afaik)

Comment: I tried styling tr and/or td with text-decoration: line-through;, but as stated, it only affects text.

Comment: What should you see if one or more cells in the row have text that wraps to multiple lines?

Comment: The table content will never expand beyond one line.

Answer (score 117, accepted):

Oh yes, yes it is!

CSS:

```
table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
}

td {
    position: relative;
    padding: 5px 10px;
}

tr.strikeout td:before {
    content: " ";
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 0;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #111;
    width: 100%;
}
```

HTML:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>Stuff</td>
        <td>Stuff</td>
        <td>Stuff</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="strikeout">
        <td>Stuff</td>
        <td>Stuff</td>
        <td>Stuff</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Stuff</td>
        <td>Stuff</td>
        <td>Stuff</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

http://codepen.io/nericksx/pen/CKjbe

Comment: I would edit the solution given to have the css applied only to a table with a class such as strike-able.  Your code may have the side effect of modifying other tables. I'll add a solution to help explain

Comment: Is there a way to get the line in red? Thanks!

Comment: FYI, the code listed is not the same as the code in the link. I believe the link is more updated. @StefanMüller change the `#111` to the color you want.

Answer (score 38):

My answer (below) said that it is not possible. I was wrong, as pointed out by @NicoleMorganErickson. Please see her answer (and upvote it!) for how to do it. In short, you use `:before` pseudo-class to create an element that draws a border across the middle of the cell, above the content:

```css
table           { border-collapse:collapse } /* Ensure no space between cells   */
tr.strikeout td { position:relative        } /* Setup a new coordinate system   */
tr.strikeout td:before {                     /* Create a new element that       */
  content: " ";                              /* …has no text content            */
  position: absolute;                        /* …is absolutely positioned       */
  left: 0; top: 50%; width: 100%;            /* …with the top across the middle */
  border-bottom: 1px solid #000;             /* …and with a border on the top   */
}
```

---

*(original answer)*

No, it is not possible using only CSS and your semantic table markup. As @JMCCreative suggests, it is possible *visually* using any number of ways to position a line over your row.

I would instead suggest using a combination of `color`, `background-color`, `font-style:italic` and/or `text-decoration:line-through` to make the entire row obviously different. (I'd personally strongly 'fade out' the text to a color much closer to the background than normal text and make it italic.)

Answer (score 14):

```
tr {
    background-image: url('data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAEAAAABCAYAAAAfFcSJAAAADUlEQVQIW2NkYGCQBAAAIwAbDJgTxgAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==');
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
    background-position: 50% 50%;
}
```

I used http://www.patternify.com/ to generate the 1x1 image url.

Answer (score 9):

### Edit

In a recent Bootstrap 4.3 ServiceNow Angular.js project, I found myself having to make some changes, and instead used the following CSS, similar to the experience of Revoman:

```
    tr.strikeout td.strike-able:before {
          content: " ";  
          position: absolute;  
          display: inline-block;  
          padding: 12px 10px;  
          left: 0;  
          border-bottom: 2px solid #d9534f;  
          width: 100%;          
    }
```

---

### Original Post

I like Nicole Morgan Erickson's answer, but it might cause side effects if your implement his solution verbatim.  I've add some small tweaks to keep this kosher, below... so that we're not globally modifying every table or every td with this CSS.

I also wanted a button on the row to strike out the row, but I didn't want to strike out the column with the button, for visibility sake. I just wanted to strike out the rest of the row.  For this, I made it so that every column that wants to be capable of showing the strike out must declare such by also being marked with a class.  In this iteration, you'd need to mark the table as strike-able, and also mark each td as strike-able; but you gain safety by not side effecting any non-strike-able tables, and you gain control of which columns to strike out.

**CSS:**

```
table.strike-able {
    border-collapse: collapse;
}

table.strike-able tr td {
    position: relative;
    padding: 3px 2px;
}

table.strike-able tr th {
    position: relative;
    padding: 3px 2px;
}

table.strike-able tr.strikeout td.strike-able:before {
    content: " ";
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 0;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #d9534f;
    width: 100%;
}
```

**Usage:**

```
<table class="strike-able" id="Medications" data-item-count="@Model.Medications.Count">
<tr>
    <th>
        Some Column
    </th>
    <th>
        Command Column
    </th>
</tr>
<tr class="strikeout">
    <td class="strike-able"></td>
    <td>Button that Toggles Striking Goes Here (active)</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td class="strike-able"></td>
    <td>Button that Toggles Striking Goes Here</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Lastly, since I'm using this with Bootstrap, and treating the deletions as a dangerous thing to do, I've formatted the colors a little to match my use.

Comment: Brilliant, thank you for this. Your use case is exactly mine down to the use of Bootstrap. We're using the DataTables plugin for jQuery and your answer appears to work perfectly with it (including sorting).

Comment: Would this work where the rendered table is from an asp:GridView ?

Answer (score 9):

**EDIT: As pointed out by @Mathieu M-Gosselin in the comments, this actually puts the line behind the text.**  That said, if your line is the same color as your text or you are using a small-ish font, this still works pretty well.

For what it's worth, here's a pretty effective way to do it in pure CSS without using pseudo elements.  You can change the thickness of the strikethrough line by adjusting the `background-size`.

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

td {
  width: 100px
}

.strikethrough {
  background: repeating-linear-gradient(
    180deg,
    red 0%,
    red 100%
  );
  background-size: 100% 2px;
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>Foo</td>
    <td>Bar</td>
    <td>Baz</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="strikethrough">
    <td>Foo Strike</td>
    <td>Bar Strike</td>
    <td>Baz Strike</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Wouldn't that put the line behind the content? Maybe you're presuming they're the same color?

Comment: Hmmm... Good point.  I edited my answer to reflect this.  It still works for my purposes! :)

Answer (score 3):

@NicoleMorganErickson, I like your answer, but I could not get the strikeout to affect only the applied row.  Also, I needed it to be applied multiple rows so I modified your solution down into a single class.

CSS:

```
tr.strikeout td:before {  
  content: " ";  
  position: absolute;  
  display: inline-block;  
  padding: 5px 10px;  
  left: 0;  
  border-bottom: 1px solid #111;  
  width: 100%;  
}
```

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/AaFpu

Comment: this maybe old, but i needed to do this and this answer was the one that worked best; the others caused side effects, or didn't "strike out" enough. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can. In the first cell of the row you create a div containing a HR.  Float the div to the left and specify its width as a % of its containing element, in this case the table cell.  It'll stretch as wide as you want across the table cells in that row, even beyond the width of the table if you want.

This works for me:

```
<style>
.strikeThrough {
height:3px;
color:#ff0000;
background-color:#ff0000;
}
.strikeThroughDiv {
float:left;
    width:920%;
    position:relative;
    top:18px;
border:none;
}
</style>
<table width="900" border="1" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="4">
   <tr  valign="bottom">
    <td>
    <div class="strikeThroughDiv"><hr  class="strikeThrough"/></div>
    One
    </td>
    <td>    
        <label for="one"></label>
        <input type="text" name="one" id="one" />
    </td>
    <td>
    <label for="list"></label>
      <select name="list" id="list">
        <option value="One">1</option>
        <option value="Two">2</option>
        <option value="Three" selected>3</option>
      </select>
    </td>
    <td>
      Four
    </td>
    <td>
      Five
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

To control the width of your line you have to specify the width of the table cell containing the HR.  For styling HR elements they say you shouldn't make it less than 3px in height.

Answer (score -1):

Here's a very simple way that worked for me:

```
<table>
<tbody style="text-decoration: line-through">
-- Various table body stuff
</tbody> </table>
```

Comment: This makes the whole table strike-though, not the row.

Answer (score -1):

Not sure but it seems there were other answers mentioning simple and straightforward pure CSS solution...

@Ben Slade's answer is the closest of all, but still...

Just use `text-decoration: line-through` in your CSS! Add corresponding class and then use `<tr class="strikethrough">`!

```css
.strikethrough {
  text-decoration: line-through;
}

table,
th,
td {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Company</th>
    <th>Contact</th>
    <th>Country</th>
  </tr>
  <tr class="strikethrough">
    <td>Centro comercial Moctezuma</td>
    <td>Francisco Chang</td>
    <td>Mexico</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Alfreds Futterkiste</td>
    <td>Maria Anders</td>
    <td>Germany</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this only strikes out the text, not the whole table row. (across borders)