# Strikethrough Table and/or DIV

Tags: javascript, html, css

I currently utilized this method [Linethrough/strikethrough a whole HTML table row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4619542/linethrough-strikethrough-a-whole-html-table-row) and it works great.

However how do I attach it to a HTML check box onclick method?

http://jsfiddle.net/deaconf19/DrEhv/

```
<table border 1>
<tr>
<td>Status</td>
<td>Priority</td>
<td>Date</td>
<td>Event</td>
<td>Updated</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td contenteditable/>Checkbox</td>
<td contenteditable/>3</td>
<td contenteditable/>02/07/2014</td>
<td contenteditable/>code needs updating again</td>
<td contenteditable/>02/07/2014</td>
</tr>
<tr class="strikeout">
<td contenteditable/>Checkbox</td>
<td contenteditable/>1</td>
<td contenteditable/>02/07/2014</td>
<td contenteditable/>code needs updating</td>
<td contenteditable/>02/07/2014</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use jQuery, to find check box parents parent and add a class to it when status of checkbox changed

```
if ( this.checked) {
  $(this).parent().parent().addClass("strikeout");
} else {
 $(this).parent().parent().removeClass("strikeout");
}
```

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/DrEhv/4/)

Comment: Perfect works like a charm really appreciate the help

Answer (score 1):

Just use javascript to change the table class. If using jQuery:

```
$('#myCheckbox').change(function(){
    $('#myTableRow').toggleClass('strikeout', $(this).prop('checked'));
})
```

The text below assumes that you have a checkbox with `id="myCheckbox"` and a table row with `id="myTableRow"`.

Answer (score 1):

Why use jQuery if **pure JS** can do the same thing:

In your HTML, add onclick handler for checkboxes:

```
<input type="checkbox" onclick="strike(this)">
```

Then change class of TR element based on checkbox value, like this:

```
function strike(elm) {
    if(elm.checked) {
        elm.parentNode.parentNode.className = "strikeout";
    } else {
        elm.parentNode.parentNode.className = "";
    }
}
```

As simple as that !

Comment: Little addendum: if your element has multiple classes (e.g. `class='strikethrough active'`), it will strip that other class too. It's not a huge problem, given the relative complexity of toggling a class in pure javascript. If you use jQuery, there are much more elegant ways to do it, but such a simple problem isn't worth including jQuery.